# Как правильно использовать модуль keyboard, чтобы отлавливать нажатие клавиши

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, клавиатура, python-keyboard

Мне требуется вставить новую строку, содержащую некоторую информацию и кнопку для удаления этой строки, в изначально пустую таблицу по нажатию клавиши **`f`** с клавиатуры. Но программа ломается при попытке добавить новую ячейку таблице. Нажатие клавишь отслеживается модулем **`keyboard`**.

Вот мой код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidgetItem, QWidget, QPushButton
import keyboard
import sys

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 400, 200
        self.resize(self.window_width, self.window_height)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.table = QTableWidget(0, 3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        keyboard.on_press_key('f', self.addRow)

    def addRow(self, event=None):

        item = QTableWidgetItem('Some text')
        btn = QPushButton('Some btn')
        currentRow = self.table.rowCount()

        self.table.insertRow(currentRow)
        self.table.setItem(currentRow, 0, item)
        self.table.setCellWidget(currentRow, 1, btn)



def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    myApp = MainWindow()
    myApp.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Я использую модуль *keyboard*, чтобы отлавливать нажатие клавиши из любого окна.
После запуска программы и нажатия на нужную клавишу окно зависает:

[image: img]

и после принудительного закрытия я получаю следующее:

> Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же я изменю код так, чтобы строка добавлялась не по нажатию на клавишу:

`keyboard.on_press_key('f', self.addRow)`

а просто вызовом функции:

`self.addRow()`

то всё работает.
Насколько я понимаю, не правильно связываю эти две библы.

Это минимизированная версия кода для описания моей проблемы. Как можно исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import keyboard
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QVBoxLayout, \
    QTableWidgetItem, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class KeyBoardManager(QObject):
    keySignal = pyqtSignal()
    
    def start(self):    
        keyboard.add_hotkey("f", self.keySignal.emit, suppress=True)    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 400, 200
        self.resize(self.window_width, self.window_height)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.table = QTableWidget(0, 3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        
#        keyboard.on_press_key('f', self.addRow)
        manager = KeyBoardManager(self)                            # +++
        manager.keySignal.connect(self.addRow)                     # +++
        manager.start()                                            # +++

    def addRow(self, event=None):
        currentRow = self.table.rowCount()
        
        item = QTableWidgetItem(f'Some text: {currentRow}')
        btn = QPushButton(f'Some btn: {currentRow}')
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print(btn.text()))

        self.table.insertRow(currentRow)
        self.table.setItem(currentRow, 0, item)
        self.table.setCellWidget(currentRow, 1, btn)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp = MainWindow()
    myApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Работает!

Comment: @DoubleTap пожалуйста.